# Updating Android Content via web?

Tags: android

I'm developing an app for a company that will include profiles of some clients. The company wants the clients to be able to update information on their profile from the company's website through a secure log-in. I want to do this in a way that the content could be updated without the application users needing to update the .APK.

I'm relatively new to Android development and I'm not quite sure how to do this. Would love the simplest way of doing this. If simple isn't the best way to go about it, I'm open to other suggestions.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- The website should have a webservice backend.
- Your Android app needs to implement the protocol  for that
  webservice.

See for example this link http://fahmirahman.wordpress.com/2011/04/21/connection-between-php-server-and-android-client-using-http-and-json/ for a tutorial or search for others.

Comment: Thank you very much. This looks to be a big help. I just wish I had some experience with PHP. Guess I need to learn some at some point, right?

Comment: You have many choices, theoretically you can write the webservice in any language. It's better to talk with the person in charge for that website to get started on the proper path.